# Desmembrar expressão numérica completa em C

Tags: c, string, parser

Olá;
Estou com um código que deve ser feito na linguagem C, que trata-se de receber uma expressão numérica, incluindo o resultado da mesma, por exemplo: "20+30=50", que será guardada numa string. Após receber a expressão, eu desejo desmembrar essa expressão, colocando cada número em uma variável int, e os operadores ("+" e "=", no caso) em variáveis do tipo char e apresentar cada um separadamente nas suas respectivas variáveis int e char. Eu consigo fazer o que desejo utilizando atoi, porém, apenas o primeiro número ("20"), o primeiro operador ("+") e o operador de igualdade ("=") que consigo guardar nas variáveis corretas, os outros números ficam vazios.
A seguir está meu código pra vocês analisarem e me ajudarem, ele não está completo ainda, preciso fazer essa leitura e "desmembramento" da string funcionar para completar o programa. Já pesquisei em vários lugares, já tirei várias dúvidas com várias pessoas, e nada foi resolvido ainda. Quem puder apontar o erro, me apresentar uma nova solução, serei muito grato.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char expressao[20];
    int tamExpressao;
    int aux1;
    int aux2;
    int aux3;
    int aux4;
    char num1[3]={0};
    char num2[3]={0};
    char num3[3]={0};
    char oper1;
    char operIgual;
    int numero1=0;
    int numero2=0;
    int numero3=0;

    printf("Digite expressao:\n");
    scanf("%s", expressao);

    printf("%s\n\n", expressao);
    tamExpressao=strlen(expressao);
    printf("%i\n\n", tamExpressao);

         for (aux1=0; aux1<tamExpressao; aux1++)
         {
             if  (expressao[aux1]=='0'|expressao[aux1]=='1'|expressao[aux1]=='2'|expressao[aux1]=='3'|expressao[aux1]=='4'|expressao[aux1]=='5'|expressao[aux1]=='6'|expressao[aux1]=='7'|expressao[aux1]=='8'|expressao[aux1]=='9')
             {
                 for (aux2=0; aux2<3; aux2++)
                 {
                     if (numero1>0)
                     {
                         if (numero2>0)
                         {
                             num3[aux2]=num3[3]+expressao[aux1];
                         } else {num2[aux2]=num2[3]+expressao[aux1];}
                     } else {num1[aux2]=num1[3]+expressao[aux1];}
                     }
                     } else if  (expressao[aux1]=='+'|expressao[aux1]=='-')
                     {
                        numero1=atoi(&num1[aux2]);
                        oper1=expressao[aux1];
                        } else if  (expressao[aux1]=='=')
                            {
                                numero2=atoi(&num2[aux2]);
                                operIgual=expressao[aux1];
                            }
         }
         numero3=atoi(&num3[3]);
                        //Apresentação dos números digitados
                        printf("%i\t%i\t%c\t%i\t%c\t%i\n", aux1, numero1, oper1, numero2, operIgual, numero3);
                        //---

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você não consegue formatar o código um pouco melhor? Não dá nem vontade de mexer em algo assim. Isto ajuda você não entender o que está fazendo. Estava tentando ler e me perdi nele.

Comment: Considera usar [`strtoull()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoul.html) em vz de `atoi()`. Com a primeira função obtens um tratamento de erro muito mais poderoso.

Comment: Use `||` e `&&` (operadores de curto circuito) ao invés de `|` e `&` nos seus ifs. Além disso, tem um cabeçalho ctype.h com funções como isdigit e isspace bastantes úteis pra você (e mais eficientes do que os seus ifs também)

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se vale a pena tentar adaptar seu código pra fazer ele funcionar. Não vai dar muito certo ter um loopzão por fora sendo que em cada iteração você quer fazer algo diferente (na primeira você quer salvar o número na primeira variável, na segunda você quer salvar o operador, na terceira você quer pegar mais um número, etc). A maneira tradicional de resolver esse seu problema é criar um "lexer" separado que lê um "token" de cada vez.

Primeiro podemos definir um tipo de dados pra representar um elemento da sua expressão:

```
enum TIPO_TOKEN = {
    TK_NUM,
    TK_OP,
    TK_EQ,
}
```

Além do tipo, você vai precisar de um lugar pra armazenar o "valor" do objeto lido. Uma maneira simples (mas gambiarrosa) é usar umas variáveis globais mesmo:

```
TIPO_TOKEN token_type;
int number_value;
char op_value;
```

Além disso, vamos precisar de manter o estado da leitura (qual a primeira posição não lida da nossa entrada). Em C o normal seria usar um ponteiro pra char pra fazer isso - assim você não precisa ficar lidando com índices o tempo todo. Além disso, como strings em C são terminadas por um`\0`, não precisa fazer um strlen pra ver quando sua entrada acaba.

```
char * next_char;
```

Com isso em mão, você pode tentar escrever uma função que lê um elemento de cada vez, e salva os valores nessas globais:

```
void init_lexer(char *str){
    next_char = str;
}

int next_token(){ 
    if(*next_char == '='){
        token_type = TK_EQ;
        ++next_char;
        return 0; //OK
    }else if(*next_char == '+' || *next_char == '-'){
        token_type = TK_OP;
        op_value = *next_char;
        ++next_char;
        return 0;
    }else if(isdigit(*next_char)){
        token_type = TK_NUMBER;
        num_value = /* ...*/ ;
        /*...*/
        return 0;
    }else{
       /*...*/
    }
}
```

Uma vez que você tenha implementado o lexer, seu main fica bem mais fácil de escrever:

```
int n1;
char op;
int n2;
int n3;

init_lexer(entrada);
if(next_token()){ /* erro: não conseguiu ler token */ }
if(token_type != TK_NUM){ /* erro: entrada nao comeca com numero */ }
n1 = num_value;
if(next_token()){ /* erro */ }
if(token_type != TK_OP){ /* erro */ }
op = op_value;
/*...*/
```

---

resumindo: O importante aqui é que vale a pena separar a seu código em um lexer, a rotina que converte a entrada de texto para uma sequências de "tokens" estruturados (o lexer) e um parser, a rotina responsável por consumir essa sequência de tokens e verificar se eles estão na ordem certa (por exemplo, "10 + + 5" é uma sequência de tokens que não faz sentido).

Já os específicos podem variar bastante - você pode usar variáveis globais ou não, unions para armazenar o valor do token, etc. Além disso, existem ferramentas externas, como como flex e bison que são muito úteis se seu programa começar a ficar mais complicado (por exemplo, o flex deixa você escrever a especificação do lexer usando expressões regulares)

Comment: Agradeço de verdade as ajudas. Porém, por se tratar de um trabalho de faculdade, por mais que seja viável, não é aceito o uso de ponteiros para solução deste trabalho. Não existe uma forma que faça o que eu quero, sem o uso de ponteiros? Eu estou realmente quebrando a cabeça, e nada que tento está funcionando. (Não se preocupem, eu não estou pedindo para vocês fazerem o trabalho por mim, ele é bem mais complexo que isso, esta é apenas uma parte do que será implementado no trabalho final). Obrigado!

Comment: Ao invés de usar um ponteiro pra marcar a posição atual, você pode usar uma combinação "ponteiro pro início da string + índice inteiro", que nemm você estava fazendo antes. Acho que no fundo você ainda vai precisar usar ponteiros se você quiser poder acessar o vetor `expressão` fora da `main` mas usando um índice inteiro você evita de fazer manipulações aritméticas nos ponteiros (que é o mais complicado).